# Temporary ID For new object rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, state-machine

I am trying to upload photos through ajax on a multistep form (which is also using ajax), The problem I am currently facing is that in order to upload a photo and keep it tied to the new object (lets call it post) the photo needs to store the posts id. But it can't do this is post is a new object and its id is nil! I have seen a lot of websites where when you click create the url looks something like this "www.example.com/post?step=create&id=134813489134" whats weird is that the id is already created, now this step is rather simple but what is the user closes the browser? Does the object stay persist or is it deleted. Thanks in advance

Comment: Why you need to upload the image before the "posts" object?

Comment: @FxckDead due to the application flow the user inputs some data, then photos, and some more data. I was wondering if I should save the data, and mark the column as a incomplete and then continue with photos. Either way I was just also curious on how other people do this.

Comment: Your photo object have an ID right? So i think your response when you upload the image must return this id (for example { "photo_id": 1}), you save this ID in some array in the current page (array in JS maybe?) and when you create the "post" object you send this array to the server and associate this photos with this "post"

Comment: @FxckDead well this may work again what happens to the photos if the user closes the page and the association between the post and the photos are never made, are they stored in the db until a worker goes in?

Comment: the photos will still in db, but i think you must implement some job to clean this images, like a cronjob (linux, mac) or a Job (mssql). I don't know how Wordpress (entry editor) or Stack Overflow (question editor)  do it, but i think other way to do it is making a "temp post" when you upload the image you create a post and associate this image to the post, see how it works on SO, but the "clean process" is a fact i think.

Comment: @FxckDead thanks but I am still trying to figure out how this might work. Thanks for your help though...